# What is the correct pattern for interdependent documents in different collections in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Suppose I want to write an app that shows a directory of team members in an organization. It has two components: **Members**, and **Projects**. A member may be part of multiple projects.
The app must allow you to browse a list of projects and see which members are part of that project. It must also allow you to tap on a member and see a list of all the projects that member is part of.

What's the correct way to structure this in Firestore? I assume it is not to duplicate the data like this:

- Members

  - name
  - projects

    - id_project
- Projects

  - name
  - members

    - id_member

I'm used to thinking in terms of relational databases and foreign keys. Since there doesn't seem to be anything like that in Firestore, what are some guidelines for ensuring the integrity of relational data?

Comment: Firestore, like all NoSQL databases, does not enforce relational integrity.  The only thing ensuring integrity is your code, and the only thing establishing relationships is, again, your code.  This means there is often not a "correct" way of modeling data.  Your data model should suit the queries you need to perform, and it is common to duplicate data within the database in order to efficiently support those queries.

Comment: I see. But if NoSQL is so poorly suited for atomic data, why are Amazon and Google pushing it so hard? It seems like everything is designed to work with DynamoDB and Firebase, while SQL is treated as legacy.

Comment: You have a variety of database options at your disposal, each with their own pros and cons, and you are free to choose the one that best suits your needs.  I will say that if you need massive scalability, it's almost certainly not going to be best met with a SQL database.  No one is deprecating SQL - there are perfectly well supported and viable SQL databases that can handle moderate loads.